# Failing in resolve reverse name

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-12.04

I can't properly resolve my reverse name. In my configs, I replaced my IP address by `X1.X2.X3.X4`, and my domain name by `domainname`. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-5.html), in which it first resolves the inverse before continue configuring.

I'm stuck in such a way that I don't know how to continue. One thing that I noticed is that he is using a local IP, and I'm using a internet IP.

Any pointers on how to debug this thing would be appreciated.

Here is my `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`:

```
logging {
    channel query.log {      
        file "/var/log/query.log"; 
        severity debug 3; 
    }; 
    category queries { query.log; }; 
};

zone "X3.X2.X1.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "zones/ptr/X3.X2.X1.db";
};

include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
```

And my `"/etc/bind/zones/ptr/X3.X2.X1.db";`

```
$TTL 3D
@   IN      SOA     ns.domainname.com. admin.domainame.com. (
                1       ; Serial
                8H      ; Refresh
                2H      ; Retry
                4W      ; Expire
                1D)     ; Minimum TTL

        NS      ns.domainname.com.
49          PTR     localhost.
```

This is the dig output, note how it is missing the answer section.

```
root@hostname:/etc/bind# dig -x X1.X2.X3.X4 @localhost

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> -x X1.X2.X3.X4 @localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 47451
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;X4.X3.X2.X1.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 27 18:26:06 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

On the `query.log`, I have the following:

```
client ::1#49304: query: X4.X3.X2.X1.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (::1)
```

Comment: You got a `SERVFAIL`, which probably means there's something useful in one of `bind`'s logs.  Could you find it and add it to your question?

Comment: @fotanus Did you restart named? Please provide log output as well,

Comment: @Flup I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and nothing poped up on syslog - where can I find the bind log? greping by `zone` on /var/log only returns daemon and syslog

Comment: Look for a `logging` section in your `named.conf` (or `named.conf.local`) or, failing that, try in `/var/log/named`.

Comment: @Flup I edited the question adding how I add the log on named.conf.local, and the output on the log file

Comment: Anything in the other files in `/var/log/named`?  Any errors when you restart bind written into those files?

Comment: At the very least it should announce its version number to syslog when it starts up. If you haven't seen that, you're looking in the wrong place. Here's a trick I use: restart the daemon, wait 5 seconds, and `ls -ltr /var/log` (sort newest files to the bottom) to see what log file just got written to. If subdirectories of `/var/log` are suspected of being involved, `find /var/log -type f -exec ls -ltr {} +` ... even if someone guesses the solution to your SERVFAIL, not knowing where your logs are is a serious problem itself and you should fix it.

Comment: @Flup There is no such file :( - I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Actually there is stuff on syslog, and is exactly what made me find the error :-) it seems I need to use the complete path on the named file : `from master file zones/ptr/X3.X2.X1.db failed: file not found`

Answer (score 1):

The problem on my case is that I couldn't have a relative path on `named.conf.local`. I needed to be a full path.

So changing

```
file "zones/ptr/X3.X2.X1.db";
```

By

```
file "/etc/bind/zones/ptr/X3.X2.X1.db";
```

Make it work.

Special thanks to @WumpusQ.Wumbley comment, which make me look on syslogd and see the error message that my file was not found.

Comment: Relative paths are legal, but they must be relative to the `directory` statement listed in the global `options {};` block. (FYI: situations such as this are we encourage posting the full configuration, not the most relevant snippets)

Comment: @AndrewB That was actually my full `named.conf.local`, the other files (including the one that is included on it) are standard ubuntu ones. Thanks for the pointer about the correct option!

Comment: Which is fine, until you factor in that we're not askubuntu. :) We've got a number of DNS experts here, but you're limiting yourself to a fraction of the exposure by omitting a stock distro config.

Comment: @AndrewB You are right, sorry for posting in the wrong place. As you can see, I use mainly stackoverflow. Please feel free to move to askubuntu if you, that uses this SE site way more than me, feel like the right thing.

Comment: Oh, no, I'm not saying that at all. It was fine for SF, but if you're gonna use SF, you can't make the same assumptions as that site. :)

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
named-checkconf /etc/named.conf
```

Then, if that passes, restart named.

Do a `dig -x X1.X2.X3.X4 @localhost`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I don't have a /etc/named.conf file. Running it on `/etc/bind/named.conf` and it don't find problems. Restarting the server and running the dig returns what I wrote on my question.